# Tracking the network bandwidth used by a process and its children

Tags: python, linux, process, network-programming, bandwidth

I'm well aware that variants of this question have been asked before, but I still haven't found a particularly good answer.

What I'm trying to do is write a Python script that will measure the current bandwidth use and the total bytes uploaded/downloaded by process and all of its children and kill it if either of these values exceeds a user-defined threshold. Its purpose will be to limit the network usage of a backup client.

I've considered a couple of options for measuring process bandwidth:

- [`bwmon`](http://thp.io/2010/bwmon/) does *exactly* what I want, but frustratingly it won't work for me in its current form. The problem is that it relies on reading `bytes=` and `packets=` fields from `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` in order to measure bandwidth. For some reason these fields just don't exist for me - I suspect it might be to do different kernel versions.
- Currently the most workable solution I've found would be to parse the output of `strace -e trace=recvfrom,sendto -p <PID>` as per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/889229/1461210). However, this is a bit messy and raises nasty permissions issues - in order to attach to an existing process I would need to `sudo strace`, and I'd prefer to avoid running shell commands with superuser privileges from within scripts.

I wonder if anyone has a more elegant suggestion?

I am not very familiar with the contents of `/proc`, but if there is some other log file that will list packet sizes and counts then I could perhaps modify `bwmon` to use this instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a programming-related answer, but: try doing this:

```
sudo modprobe ip_conntrack
sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct=1
```

Enabling the module and sysctl setting globally is distribution-specific, but at least until you reboot, `bwmon` should work if it needs `bytes` and `packets` in `/proc/net/ip_conntrack`.

Based on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2046187 and http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-6677939.html (and thereby ultimately on Google).

Comment: Nice, that seemed to do the trick: `bytes=` and `packets=` are now reported in `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` and `bwmon` now seems to work ok!


For anyone else who might be interested, I added `ip_conntrack` to `/etc/modules` so that it loads at boot time, and I added `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make logging of packet size and count persistent.